Using GCC on Apple M2 Max Laptop
I can't use GCC because clang interferes with it. I used brew install gcc, and it downloaded correctly but I can't use it because clang overrides it. I added the path into my /.bash_profile so when I activate my environment it should be the first export path listed, but it didn't help. Then I manually just typed in export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0_1/bin:$PATH" straight in terminal and it still won't work. I keep getting this error when I try to run snpArcher:
Output: Encountered problems while solving:   - nothing provides requested gcc 13.2.0**

When I type gcc --version, it brings up
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0Thread model: posixInstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

How am I able to use GCC for snpArcher? Or is there a workaround to using snpArcher on an Apple M2 Max Laptop?

What's the output of type gcc and which gcc?

This question is similar to: Conflict between gcc and clang when compiling a code on Mac Osx El Capitan. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It looks like gcc 13.2.0 is not the same as gcc 14.1.0-1, or am I missing something?
